# How to easily get a zipcode from a generic address with google maps api?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to get the postal code of a generic address such as "los angeles, ca".  When I do this:

```
gcode = new google.maps.Geocoder()
gcode.geocode({'address': 'Los Angeles, CA'}, function(results, status) { log(results); });
>> [Object { address_components=[4], formatted_address="Los Angeles, CA, USA", geometry={...}, more...}]
```

I get an object returned that does not have a zipcode...  However, if I then take the location object returned from that, then I do get access to a zipcode:

```
gcode.geocode({'latLng': results[0].geometry.location}, function(results, status) { log(results[0].address_components[7].long_name) });
>> "90012"
```

..  But this seems wasteful as I am having to make two calls to the API to do this..  Is there a way to force Google to initially give me a zipcode?

Comment: LA is a huge city.  I assume LA has more than one zip-code, and that the lat/long are just some point they've defined that happens to be in LA.  If this is the case, the behavior you described makes some sense.

Comment: But even using a smaller city like "Beverly Hills, CA" does not return a zipcode...  Is it not possible to tell google to just give me an estimated zipcode without making two trips to the API?

Comment: There are still several for Beverly Hills.  I think the Google API will fail to give you zip code information almost uniformly, because there are almost always multiple zip code per city.  You'll have to deal with that case, whether or not some smaller cases do give the zip code.  It sounds like you'll just have to make multiple calls...

Comment: Hmm.. That still seems so strange to me because "Beverly Hills, CA" will give me a lat & lng..  And that lat & lng corresponds to a zipcode...  So why wouldn't it just give all the pertinent data related to that lat & lng?

Answer (score 13):

Why not using (for instance 1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View is your address)

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false
```

And then parse the JSON for

```
"long_name": "94043",
  "short_name": "94043",
  "types": [ "postal_code" ]
} ]
```

see here -> http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: But, as I stated in my question, I need to get a zipcode for a generic location such as "Beverly Hills, CA".  Not a specific address....

Comment: I don't think this answer should have been downvoted, as the original poster appears to have been misinformed on how zip codes work in the US. The last two digits of a 5 digit zip code usually determine the area of the city, not the city itself like he wanted. The first three digits will correspond with the state and region. He gets a zip code from the his second query because he is introducing coordinates to a region which the Google API can determine a zip code from.

Comment: This is not the answer. Sometimes the zip code is included in an address that dosen't have a `"types":["postal_code"]`